# Usercake Login abrupt not possible

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, usercake

I use UserCake at a Website and the login worked well,
now it's the second time in 2 days the login doesn't work,
the last login stamp in the MySQL database changes to the login attempt but I just come back to the login page

anyone an idea?

Comment: Code is the same as on UserCake shared, worked well without problems but now 2nd time the login isn't possible

Comment: Got it solved, the maximum limit of storage of my webhoster is reached